# How factory is implemented inside UVM?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, uvm

In UVM, factory is the most important thing. So how it is implemented inside. Means how it stores the various objects and create a universal database.

I know something like it has some assossiative arrays, one with key as object name and another with key as object type. But I don't know how this 2 arrays can build the database? Even I don't know that my information is proper or not.

Please also list out some related classes for factory implementation and modification. (Like umv_resource is one maybe.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This DVcon paper [Using Parameterized Classes and Factories: The Yin and Yang of Object-Oriented Verification](http://go.mentor.com/yin-and-yang) was written with the UVM factory in mind before it was publicly released. All the same principals apply.

Comment: Thanks @dave_59. Just another question, is this factory database, uvm_config_db database, uvm_resource_pool database all are the same database or not?

Comment: Thanks a lot for that paper, it gave a very good idea about factory, but I don't understand whatever can be done with factory class (according to the paper) can also be done through hierarchical access. Like if we want to change the transaction in the sequencer, then we can create an object of derived transaction and hierarchically replace it inside sequencer class  (env.agent.sequencer.trans = new_trans_object). Then what is the specific use of factory??

Comment: @dave_59, Please add key points to your answer. Link only answer are considered low quality and are at risk of being flagged. Links should add to the answer (supporting documentation, citation, further reading, etc.), not be the answer.

Comment: The key feature of the factory is that it lets you change how your code behaves without having to change your code. In the UVM, the overrides can be made at the top-level test, or even dynamically from the command line. Modifying by hierarchical access is not always possible because you don't know when the lower level code is going to construct a new object. The *Factory Design Pattern* is very common in Object-Oriented programming.